# Is the electric field a Force?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, coulombs-law

Coloumb force that act between two charges is equal to :

\begin{gather} F=KQ_{}Q_{0}/r^2 \end{gather}

And this Coloumb force has units of Newton .

But the electric field is defined as

\begin{gather} E=F/Q_{0}=KQ/r^2 \end{gather}  with units of $(N/C)$

The interpretation of electric field is that the force that act on $1$ Coloumb of charge

But is this interpretation correct?

Like how it is the force and has units of $(N/C)$ ? It should have the units of Newton

and The electric field will be no more than like a coloumb force that has the test charge $Q_{0} = 1$, it's like saying that $E=F=KQQ_{0}/r^2$ but with condition that $Q_{0}=1$,,this will be the result if the interpretation is correct

I'am so confused about the interpretation of it and how it's defined like how it will be the force and has units of $(N/C)$ ? And also the field doesn't depend on charge, if so, how we state in our definition the charge must be 1 coloumb?

Comment: The electric field is not a force. You figured this out yourself when you wrote down what units it has. You can think of it this way: The Electric field will tell you the force which will be applied to a unit charge if you place it at a certain place.

Comment: @ΜπαμπηςΠοζουκιδης, so the electric field is not a Force because we divided the Force by the charge? So can we think of the electric field at a point as: electric field vector at a point equal to force  vector divided by the point charge at this point? So can we think of electric field as the force per charge?

Comment: You can think about it like: the electric field tells you what force a 1C test charge would feel at any point in space. The field is not a force, as it has different units, but they are related.

Comment: The electric field is its own thing. It is what gives rise to a force or applies a force on charges (the exact semantics are debatable).

Comment: @klippo 
but what makes the field strength $E$ not a force ? is the reason only the units or something else ?

Comment: This might be a silly analogy but... Imagine you are at a food festival. Wherever you go on the festival ground next to you is a store ready to give you a snack. Depending on where you stand you'll get a different snack. I think it's clear that the collection of stores at the food festival and the actual food you gonna get from standing next to one are two different things. In this analogy, the field is the stores at the food festival and the food you will get from one is the force.

Comment: @amin Be careful about assigning a physical meaning to units. For example, a newton meter can be a unit of energy or a unit of torque, two entirely different things.

Comment: You can think of it as a force field, where you can have more or less charge to get more or less of the field.

Comment: @amin Asking "what makes the field strength not a force?" is like asking what makes an elephant not an apple. They are just different things. Nothing "makes" them different, they just are.

Comment: The comment by @ΜπαμπηςΠοζουκιδης is correct, but it is quite close to replicating the imprecision that caused amin's confusion in the first place. Cf. my answer below.

Comment: Instead of interpreting an electric field as *"the force that acts on 1
 Coloumb of charge*" then rather think of it as "*the force that would act per unit of charge*". Then an electric field is just a measure for how forces would be acting from any point in space if a charge of any size would be placed there.

Answer (score 12):

An electric field is not itself a force, but it *exerts* a force on a test charge. This force is proportional to the field strength $E$ at the location of the test charge *and also* proportional to the size of the test charge $Q$. So

$F = kEQ$

where $k$ is a constant of proportionality. If we measure $E$ in units such that a field strength of $1$ unit exerts a force of $1$ newton on a charge of $1$ coulomb (or a force of $2$ newtons on a charge of $2$ coulombs etc.)  then the constant of proportionality $k$ becomes $1$, which is convenient, and we have

$F = EQ$

Notice that this allows us to calculate the force on *any* test charge as long as we know the field strength and the size of the test charge - there is nothing special about a test charge of $1$ coulomb.

So, if we are working in SI units, $E$ is measured in newtons per coulomb, which we can show is equivalent to volts per metre.

Comment: but what makes the electric field strength $E$ not a force ?

Comment: Compare the electric field to your hand. The field is not a force, your hand is not a force. If you press your hand against something, your hand exerts a force, which is greater the more you press. In the same way, an electric field "presses" against particles - not at all if the particle is neutral, but the more charge on the particle, the higher the force. But at no point does your hand become a force in itself.

Answer (score 8):

The electric field generated by a charge  is not a force. A force is only experienced when another electric charge is located in the field. Then both charges experience an equal and opposite force per Newton’s third law.

Similarly the gravitational field (force per unit mass} is not a force. The gravitational field $E_g$ produced by mass $M$

$$E_{g}=\frac{GM}{r^2}$$

only produces a force $F_g$ when another mass $m$ is placed in the field where $F_g$ is

$$F_{g}=\frac{GMm}{r^2}$$

Think of the field (electric or gravitational) as the *potential* effect (potential for a force) on a charge or mass being placed in the field, whereas a force is the *actual* effect on a charge or mass  being placed in the field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but what makes the electric field strength $E$ not a force ?

Comment: The electric field strength is a measure of the intensity of an electric field at a particular location. The standard unit is Volts per meter (V/m). Since the unit for voltage is J/C, or N m/C, V/m becomes N/C.

Comment: Why did you delete the comment that I just responded to?

Comment: but when we measure the field strength $E$ we require the force for measuring it because we say $E=F/Q$ ,so my question what makes it differ from force ?

Comment: Think of the field as the POTENTIAL effect (potential force) of a charge on another charge, whereas the force is the ACTUAL effect of the charge  on another charge placed in the field.

Comment: @amin See update to my answer.

Comment: But what do you mean by potential effect? And why defining it as the potential effect cancels out being a Force? What is the reason than is not a Force?

Comment: @amin Dictionary definition of Potential: "having or showing the capacity to become or develop into something in the future".

Comment: I feel like reading the answers to this question triggered something like semantic satiation except instead of a word becoming meaningless I can't tell if the answer is philosophical or real.

Comment: @Michael sorry but I don’t understand what you’re saying

Comment: @BobD All this talk about the electric field only exerting a force if a charge was present was inducing some kind of existential conundrum in my brain making the answer seem more philosophical than grounded in reality (similar to the "if a tree falls in the forest"), but then I read an answer in a different question about the field representing the "interface" while the implementation was "the aggregate effect of the exchange of virtual particles governed by a quantum field theory" and sanity was restored.

Comment: @Michael I have no idea what you are talking about. For me, this discussion is ended

Answer (score 5):

The electric field is a vector magnitude that at each point in space has a magnitude and a direction. The direction is given by the direction in which a positive charge would move if we place it at that point. The magnitude is given by the force that the field generates on a charge placed at that point, that is, the force per unit charge. The field exists even if we do not place any charge in it, and when we place it, it generates a force that is equal to the value of the field at that point multiplied by the placed charge.

This is the same as saying that a speed is the same as a distance, because 25 meters is the same as a speed of 25m/s if I set the time to 1 second. This does not make sense. The velocity tells me how much I move forward for each second I add to my trajectory. The field tells me how much force it makes for each charge I add.

Answer (score 5):

If the vector field property is not clear, consider a completely different subject.  Consider pressure and force within an inflated balloon.  The compressed air has pressure greater than standard air pressure throughout the balloon, but the pressure only creates force at the inner surface of the balloon.  The pressure does not have a specific direction within the balloon.  The force created on the surface is outward, perpendicular to the balloon's inner surface.  The pressure only creates force where it has a surface to press against.  Likewise, the electric field only creates electric force only where it has an electric charge to push on or pull on.

Answer (score 3):

The force, $F$, (unit $\rm N$), on a charge $Q$, (unit $\rm C$), placed a a point where the electric field strength is $E$, (unit $\rm N/C)$, is given by the equation

$F$ (unit $\rm N$) = $E$ (unit $\rm N/C) \times Q$ (unit $\rm C$)

Note that if the charge happens to be one coulomb then the numerical value of the electric field strength is the force, in newtons, on the charge.

Comment: But what makes the field strength $E$ not a Force? because we require the force in our definition for Field $E=F/Q$

Answer (score 3):

The "electric field" is a mathematical object that is a function that takes as its input a point in space and gives as output a vector. Stated another way, $E: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R ^3$ (although if we're being precise, the domain is an affine space, while the codomain is a vector space). It is the gradient of the electric potential $V: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

The important point here is that the electric field is treated as a property *of space*. You put in a point, and you get out a vector. The position is the only input to the function. Given an electric field, you know what the value at particular location is without having to refer to anything else. In particular, it is defined in such a way that we don't need to know how much charge is in a particular location to know what the electric field acting on charges in that location is. To do this, we divide the force experienced by a charge by the quantity of charge, giving the electric field in units of N/C. So, no, it's not a force.

Similarly, the electric potential field (which, as state above, the electric field is the gradient of), does not have units of J, but rather units of J/C, or volts. When we talk about the electric potential at a point, we are talking about a property of that location in space, and so it is the same for all charges, and so we divide out by charge.

You can compare this to gravity. It would make no sense to ask "What is the gravitational force at this point?" because the strength of the gravitational force is different for different masses. Instead, we have to ask what the force per mass is.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the other answers are missing the point that this is simply about an imprecise use of language.

As you acknowledge in the question, the electric field *by definition* is the force *per* charge, i.e. $E=F/q$. Which means by definition it has units of $N/C$. You could also say this as "the force per unit charge", but saying the electric field is "the force *on* a unit charge" is not correct. The force on a unit charge is the product of the force per unit charge and the unit charge itself, i.e. you'll put the same number on it, but with units of $N$ instead of $N/C$.

Example: Where we measure an electric field of $10\,N/C$ the force *on* a unit charge would be $F=E*q=F/q*q=10\,N/C*1\,C=10\,N$ whereas the force *per* unit charge will just be $10\,N/C$, the electric field.

Answer (score 1):

The force per unit charge is the "density" of the electric force. Therefore it is not a force exerted on a particular body and it cannot be used directly in Newton's 2nd law. Likewise the per capita income is not the income of a particular individual so that the individual can be taxed!

Answer (score -1):

The other answers are excellent technical answers. If by chance you are looking for a visual, I think of fields as terrain (rocky, muddy, a stream, etc.). The force associated with the field is what you stumble over, what slows you down, or what diverts your path as you cross the field. It is an imperfect analogy, but it does the job.
I think of Potential Energy as how challenging the terrain is. Electrical Potential is odd. V = energy/charge, so a giant can more easily ignore the effects of terrain.
Feel free to tear my answer to shreds if you have a better, practical visual - a way you could explain it to my mom.